# Are angular material and flex layout compatible with each other?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-flex-layout, angular15

I use the latest angular and material (15) but I want to use also flex layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same problem. I tried to port an Angular 14 app to 15 today and I faced several issues. A typical Angular/Flex Layout/Angular Material app, that also uses theming to be more precise.

1. I had to use the --force flat as already pointed out
2. There was an issue with a sass warning, which was apparently fixed with version 15.0.2 of Angular
3. The app compiles but there is an issue related to theming.

I decided to go stay on version 14 until it's possible to upgrade without issues. However, if you want to be able to upgrade to later versions in the future you should move away from Flex Layout.

Answer (score 2):

According to this [blog post](https://blog.angular.io/modern-css-in-angular-layouts-4a259dca9127#6a7d) from the Angular team, `@angular/flex-layout` will no longer receive any updates. The same blog post gives guidance how to replace it.

Answer (score -2):

Yes they are compatible, just try it out

Comment: That's false. If you read the actual question, it relates to Angular 15. Since flex-layout have dependencies for major version of Angular, and version 15 of flex-layout has not been released as of now, it will NOT work. One could try using -force flag, but that's far from safe choice.

Comment: @TotallyNewb what ca be used instead of flex layout?

Comment: That's highly opinion based, and depending on which parts of flex layout you want to rely on. Note that there is an [issue on the github](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/issues/1430) stating that support for v15 is underway with a pending PR, so you might want to wait on that. Or just use pure css solution with media queries.

Comment: @TotallyNewb yes I know about the problem, in my opinion the best solution is to go back to the older version

Comment: I misunderstood the question, but in another way.
I thought he wanted to know if he can use flexbox, not flex layout, my bad